# Horizontal scrollbar on table with sticky header

Tags: html, css, sticky

im trying to implement a horizontal scrollbar on table with sticky header, the problem is scrollbar is not appearing when i implement stickiness. it can only be scrolled via trackpad and not by a mouse. im using ng2 smart table for angular

```
 <ng2-smart-table
                      *ngIf="showMainTable"
                      [settings]="settings"
                      [source]="localDataSource"
                      (edit)="rowEdited($event, 'edit')"
                      (editConfirm)="rowEdited($event, 'editConfirm')"
                    ></ng2-smart-table>
```

styles

```
:host /deep/ ng2-smart-table table tr td:first-child {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: white !important;
  // box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);

  border-left: none !important;
  border-right: none !important;
  border-top: none !important;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #f4f2f0 !important;

  box-shadow: 10px 0 10px -2px rgb(245, 241, 241) !important;
}

:host /deep/ ng2-smart-table table tr th:first-child {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: white !important;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

:host /deep/ ng2-smart-table table tr th:first-child {
  z-index: 2;
  background: white !important;
}

:host /deep/ ng2-smart-table table thead tr {
  position: sticky;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 10px 40px !important;
  top: 0;
  background: white !important;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

:host /deep/ ng2-smart-table table thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: white !important;
  border: none;
  color: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0;
  height: 56px;
  padding-left: 56px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  outline: none !important;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

:host /deep/ ng2-smart-table table tr:nth-child(1) th {
  // display: inline-flex !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 10px 40px !important;
}

:host /deep/ .ng2-smart-sort-link {
  // display: inline-flex !important;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54) !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  font-weight: 500 !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

:host /deep/ ng2-smart-table table tbody {
  // overflow: hidden;
}

:host /deep/ ng2-smart-table table {
  border: none;
}

:host /deep/ ng2-smart-table table tr td {
  // display: inline-flex !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  height: 48px;
  padding: 0 0 0 56px;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #111;
  white-space: nowrap;
  // overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border-left: none !important;
  border-right: none !important;
  border-top: none !important;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #f4f2f0 !important;
}
```

the host and deep are angular selectors, it applies style to the table generated by that
i wrapped the table in a container and i was able to implement the scroll functionality, but the table lost its stickiness. i want the headers to be sticky and table to have a fixed horizontal scrollbar at the bottom which is always visible.

i wrapped the table in a container

```
<div
                    class="table-flow"
                    [ngClass]="{ 'disable-cover': mainTableLoading }"
                  >
                    <ng2-smart-table
                      *ngIf="showMainTable"
                      [settings]="settings"
                      [source]="localDataSource"
                      (edit)="rowEdited($event, 'edit')"
                      (editConfirm)="rowEdited($event, 'editConfirm')"
                    ></ng2-smart-table>
                  </div>
```

style

```
.table-flow {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

it displays the scrollbar but i lost the sticky headers

Codesandbox Link https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-satoshi-7ycxm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have fixed this issue by providing the container a fixed max height, that way it will have the sticky header and scrolling as well.

```
.table-flow {
  max-height: 555px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  max-width: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table-flow needs to be position:relative atleast and you need to set him max width for example to 100% and then set overflow: auto :)

Comment: i tried it, but its not working , can you check the codesandbox link i just updated- https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-satoshi-7ycxm

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="table-container">
  <ng2-smart-table
    [settings]="settings"
    [source]="source"
  ></ng2-smart-table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table-container {
  height: 600px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}    

::ng-deep table tr:first-child th {
  position: sticky !important;
  top: -1px;
  z-index: 100;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  height: 58px;
}
```